# set focus on first checkbox if none selected

Tags: jquery

i was doing this in javascript, how can I set focus to first checkbox in jquery.

```
var chk = document.getElementsByName('program[]');
var len = chk.length;
var checked = false;
for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
     if(chk[i].checked) {
        checked = true;
        break;    
      } 
}
if( !checked ) {
    chk[0].focus();
    document.getElementById('errpgm').innerHTML = "Please select at 
            least one program";
    errcount++;
}
```

Comment: Just set the autofocus attribute on the first element ?

Comment: i don't want focus on first element, I want focus on checkbox if user has not selected any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already focus without jQuery, and it works: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Fxuv3/ (tested in Chrome and IE).
What is your actual problem?

**EDIT** So why do everything with jQuery (maybe just make a function out of your existing code 'focusFirstUncheckedCheckbox(name)')?

But of course you can: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Fxuv3/1/

```
if (!$('input[name^=program]:checked').length) {
    $('input[name^=program]')[0].focus();
}
```

Comment: i want to do it in jquery

Comment: Updated my answer to use jQuery only.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: My answer is valid assuming you want to focus when the page loads

Better use [`autofocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_autofocus_attribute) attribute.

In general, using javascript to set focus automatically isn't a good idea, because you have to wait until the element you want to focus has been loaded to the DOM. But if you wait to much, then the user could have focused another input, and your change of focus will be annoying.

Comment: Although he/she might have been asking the X Y problem, this is the best solution. 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: +1, this does answer the question as it stands, but the fact that the OP's code checks for checked boxes would be an indicator that it runs on an event, like a form submit, and that setting the autofocus attribute on page load isn't an option.

Comment: Please note that `autofocus` does not work in IE8 or IE9. ([source](http://caniuse.com/#search=autofocus))

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').first().focus();
```

or

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').eq(0).focus();
```

or

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:first').focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this (not tested):

```
$('[type=checkbox]:first').focus();
```